# LXD snappy add and run continer

Tags: lxc, ubuntu-core, lxd

I have to install and run Ubuntu Snappy on the Raspberry pi 2. and I have install the LXD container using the command:

```
sudo snappy install lxd.stgraber
```

now i want to start make containers and run it.  Could any one advice me the steps in terms of how to make and run a container?

Answer (score 1):

See https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/getting-started-cli/

Note that the snap package hasn't been updated in quite a while and needs a significant amount of work to be ported to current snappy, so it may well not work at all right now.